# How do i give a youtube video drop shadow

Tags: video, youtube, dropshadow

I'm trying to give a youtube video a drop shadow.

how can i do this with css?

I have tried to use a image background behind to youtube video but when using the positions properties it conflicts with other divs

Answer (score 0):

You can set the box shadow in the style for the element:

```
    #my_youtube_embed {
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 3px 3px 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 3px 3px 10px;
        -o-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 3px 3px 10px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 3px 3px 10px;
    }
```